# wxpython button held down event

Tags: button, wxpython

hey all,
im looking for a way of catching a button held down event in wxpython i cant seem to find anything. theres just wx.EVT_BUTTON which isnt quite what i want. i want my event to continue processing as long as the button is down. any help would be appreciated
thanks james

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would catch the EVT_LEFT_DOWN and the EVT_LEFT_UP. Then start a wx.Timer to run your process on EVT_LEFT_DOWN until the EVT_LEFT_UP is fired. Alternatively, you could use a ToggleButton.

Comment: hey mike thanks for the quick reply.. i tried that approach was wondering if there was another way.. what i dont like about the way you suggested is it seems so messy, say i click on the button then the timer starts, if i keep my left mouse button down and slide it off the button the timer keeps going cos the leftup was bound to the button.. any further suggestions other than checking for enter and leave the button window events?

Comment: @James, what you want is fairly unusual so it's reasonable for it to take a few lines of code, and following Mike's answer, it's only, like, six lines.  It would be highly inefficient and pretty messed up for wx to continue firing events while the mouse button is held down.

Comment: i suppose thats true, i was trying to make a scroll button for my own scroll box.. so while the button was held down the windows contents would scroll.. thanks tho for your help guys i got it working

Comment: @Mike Driscoll   :  I have tried as you suggested , but if we press the button continuously for 5 to 6 times , window gets hung, and we can operate any other things on window.

Comment: Not sure why that doesn't work without having the code to play with myself.