# wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN - evt.skip() doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, keydown, onkeydown, wxtextctrl

I created a gui in wxpython. I tried to use wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN. When I press a key, I want to know if the key changed the messageTxt (It was't a key such as right, shift, alt etc...). 
I prints the messageTxt before and after the evt.Skip() but it doen't changes, only in the second char i can see the last changes. Someone know how do I get the new messageTxt after the evt.Skip()?
By that, I could compare the text before the skipping and after and get the result it there was a change.
Here is some code that explaines the problem.

```
import wx
from wx.stc import StyledTextCtrl


def On_KeyDown(evt):
    x, y = messageTxt.GetSelection()
    # If something is selected, de-select it
    if x != y:
        messageTxt.SetEmptySelection(y)
    else:
        print("Before skipping", messageTxt.GetText())
        evt.Skip()
        print("After skipping", messageTxt.GetText())


app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, title='2', pos=(0, 0), size=(500, 500))
frame.Show(True)
messageTxt = StyledTextCtrl(frame, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=(0, 0), size=(100 * 3, 100),
                            style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, name="File")

messageTxt.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, On_KeyDown)

app.SetTopWindow(frame)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `EVT_KEY_DOWN` *is* working.
The key down event occurs before the key itself is recognised.
You should check the `EVT_KEY_UP` and then test for your `special` keys.

```
import wx
from wx.stc import StyledTextCtrl

def On_KeyDown(evt):
    x, y = messageTxt.GetSelection()
    # If something is selected, de-select it
    if x != y:
        messageTxt.SetEmptySelection(y)
    else:
        evt.Skip()

def On_KeyUp(evt):
    print("Text :", messageTxt.GetText())
    k = evt.GetKeyCode()
    if k in (wx.WXK_SHIFT,wx.WXK_ALT,wx.WXK_CONTROL,wx.WXK_DOWN):
        print('Special key')
    evt.Skip()

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, title='2', pos=(0, 0), size=(500, 500))
frame.Show(True)
messageTxt = StyledTextCtrl(frame, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=(0, 0), size=(100 * 3, 100),
                            style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, name="File")

messageTxt.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, On_KeyDown)
messageTxt.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, On_KeyUp)

app.SetTopWindow(frame)
app.MainLoop()
```

However you will need to seperate these functions into wx.EVT_KEY_UP and wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN functions or they will work at cross purposes to each other i.e. either the key changing test will work and the selection fails or vice-versa.

You may be misunderstanding `wx.event.Skip()`

> Skip(self, skip=True)
>   This method can be used inside an event handler to control whether further event handlers bound to this event will be called after the current one returns.
>
> Without Skip (or equivalently if Skip(false) is used), the event will not be processed any more. If Skip(true) is called, the event processing system continues searching for a further handler function for this event, even though it has been processed already in the current handler.
>
> In general, it is recommended to skip all non-command events to allow the default handling to take place. The command events are, however, normally not skipped as usually a single command such as a button click or menu item selection must only be processed by one handler.

Comment: Do you know how to make the key "goes up"? for example: I press long time on delete key and I want that every 0.1 sec will be count as one click.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329377/wxpython-button-held-down-event